# Как изменить фон активити программно?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть две картинки "one.png" и "two.png". По умолчанию у меня стоит "one.png" как фон
`android:background="@drawable/one"/>`

Как я могу изменить фон на "two.png" при нажатии на кнопку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно установить на том layout где установлен фон `android:background="@drawable/one"` id примерно вот так:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/one"/>
```

Аналогично на кнопку добавляете id. Затем в activity добавляете код:

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout_id);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.two);
        }
    });
```

Дополнение: тип layout в коде естественно надо поменять с LinearLayout на тот, что используется у вас.

Answer (score 2):

Отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8929240/5892568
В листенере делаете:

```
 getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.two);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете в качестве ресурсов фона не изображение, а файл xml, то Вам подойдет только этот способ:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background2);
```